# Efficient way to check if it is a subset of any group in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, set

What is an efficient way to iterate `subset_candidates` and check if it is a subset of any set of `groups` in Python?
Sample below has only a few items, but I expect 10k of subset_candidates and 10k of groups, so I want to know the efficient way.
Maybe `networkX` is the solution but I don't know which method should be applied to this case.

```py
subset_candidates = [
  [2, 3], # true (subset of groups[0]) 
  [10, 12], # false
  [100, 110], # true (subset of groups[2])
  [1, 10, 100], # false
]

groups = [
  [1,2,3],
  [10,11,13],
  [100, 105, 110],
]
```

Comment: How about [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)?

Comment: if type is only list then something like this: `all(x in group for x in subset)`

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev Better to change the type for the complexity of the search.

Comment: @dspencer that's a good solution, I didn't know that. but it has to loop `groups` every time. Is this the only approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this using [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)

```
s=map(set,subset_candidates)
g=list(map(set,groups))

for subset in s:
    print(any(subset.issubset(i) for i in g))
```

---

Output

```
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: No need to make `s` a list - `map` object is fine (in case of `g`, however, a list is necessary because you're iterating over it multiple times)

Comment: Is this the only approach? it has to loop groups everytime and number of iterations would be 10k x 10k.

Comment: Ofcourse not...But to give a optimized solution we have to know how you obtain the `subset_candidates` and we have to know the what's your data structure....If the subsets are random then you have to do `n x n` searches. But if there's a relation for example `subset_candidates` is always sorted and `groups` is also sorted then search reduces to `O(logn)` then we can reduce complexity. @harry

Answer (score 0):

Convert each list in `subset_candidates` and each `list` in `groups` to `set`. Then, for each set in `subset_candidates` check if [`issubset(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)